NODE_ENV Not Set Correctly in React Native Project on macOS
I am working on a React Native project on macOS, and I am facing an issue where the NODE_ENV environment variable is not being set correctly. Despite trying various methods to set this variable, it remains undefined when the project runs. I have attempted multiple approaches including using cross-env, setting the variable directly in the terminal, updating the babel.config.js file, and following the documentation for react-native-dotenv and react-native config, but none have resolved the issue.
Steps Taken:
Installed cross-env:
npm install --save-dev cross-env

Updated package.json scripts:
{
  "scripts": {
    "check:env": "cross-env echo $NODE_ENV",
    "android:dev": "react-native run-android",
    "android:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production react-native run-android",
    "ios:dev": "react-native run-ios",
    "ios:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production react-native run-ios"
  }
}

Updated babel.config.js to load environment variables:
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// Load .env file based on NODE_ENV
const envFile = `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'}`;
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), envFile) });

console.log('NODE_ENV:', process.env.NODE_ENV); // Should show the correct value
console.log('Using dotenv file:', envFile);

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  return {
    presets: ["module:@react-native/babel-preset"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          alias: {
            "@": "./src",
            "@images": "./src/asset/images",
            "@components": "./src/components",
            "@view": "./src/view/index.ts",
            "@utils": "./src/utils",
            "@store": "./src/store",
            "@constants": "./src/constants",
            "@texts": "./src/components/texts",
          },
        },
      ],
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
      [
        "module:react-native-dotenv",
        {
          envName: "APP_ENV",
          moduleName: "@env",
          path: envFile,
          blocklist: null,
          allowlist: null,
          safe: false,
          allowUndefined: true,
          verbose: false,
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};

Tried setting the variable directly in the terminal:
export NODE_ENV=production
npm run android:prod

Verified the .env files exist:
.env.development
.env.production

Followed documentation for react-native-dotenv:
Installed and configured as per react-native-dotenv documentation.
Tried using react-native config:
Followed the setup and configuration steps as per the React Native documentation.
Observed Output:
Despite these steps, the output still shows NODE_ENV as undefined:
transform[stdout]: NODE_ENV: undefined
transform[stdout]: Using dotenv file: .env.development

Additional Details:
macOS version: Sonoma 14.5
Node.js version: 21.1.0
npm version: 10.8.1
React Native version: 0.74.3

I have also tried using env-cmd, and even hardcoding the environment variable directly in the configuration, but the issue persists. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this problem.
What am I missing or doing wrong?
